# SSIS - "switchable" file output for debug?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

In an SSIS data-flow task, I'm using a Multicast transform at a key part of the flow which I want to hang a File Output destination off.

This, in itself, is no problem to do. However I only want output in the file if I enable it; i.e., I'd be using it for debugging the data if the flow fails unexpectedly and it's not immediately obvious from the default log message output why this occured.

My initial thought was to create a File Output whose output file was obtained from a variable, and by default, the variable would contain 'nul' - i.e., the Windows bit-bucket - which I could override through configuration in the event of needing to dig further.

Unfortuantly this isn't working: the File Output complains saying that "The filename is a device or contains invalid characters". So it looks like I can't use the bit-bucket.

Is anyone aware of a way to make output "switchable"? This would make enabling debug a less risky proposition than editing the package and dropping a File Output in directly.

I suppose I could have a Conditional Split off the multi-cast which basically sends output if a variable is set to some given value, but this seems overly messy, I'll be poking other options, but if anyone has any suggestions/solutions, they'd be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the conditional split, redirecting rows to the konesans trash destination adaptor if your variable wasn't set, otherwise send to your file.

Comment: Yep, not found any better myself. Cheers.